# How to enable extensions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE chat (
    message_uuid    UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
);
```

which fails with the following error message:

```
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
```

As far as I can see, I need an extension to make use of this function. Does anyone know how I can activate it? The function seems to exist according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable the [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-uuid/) extension. Execute this statement:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```